# HTTP MAC Authentication using C#

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, hmac

I'm trying to create a client for the new tent.io protocol that's being developed and they are using the HTTP MAC Oauth2 scheme described by https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-http-mac-01.

I've written a simple method in C# that creates the Authorization header, but when I submit my request I get a simple "Invalid MAC signature" error.

Since I don't have a reference implementation, I'm struggling to figure out what's wrong with my code. I'm posting it here in the hope that somebody can spot my mistake.

```
public string GetAuthorizationHeader(string macKeyIdentifier, string macKey, string macAlgorithm, string method, Uri uri)
{
    TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
    string timestamp = ((int)t.TotalSeconds).ToString();

    string nonce = new Random().Next().ToString();

    string normalizedString = string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n\n", 
                                            timestamp, 
                                            nonce, 
                                            method,
                                            uri.PathAndQuery, 
                                            uri.Host, 
                                            uri.Port);

    HashAlgorithm hashGenerator = null;
    if (macAlgorithm == "hmac-sha-256")
    {
        hashGenerator = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(macKey));
    }
    else if (macAlgorithm == "hmac-sha-1")
    {
        hashGenerator = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(macKey));
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported MAC algorithm");
    }

    string hash = System.Convert.ToBase64String(hashGenerator.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(normalizedString)));

    StringBuilder authorizationHeader = new StringBuilder();
    authorizationHeader.AppendFormat(@"id=""{0}"",ts=""{1}"",nonce=""{2}"",mac=""{3}""",
                                     macKeyIdentifier, timestamp, nonce, hash);

    return authorizationHeader.ToString();
}
```

I create the full header using the returned value and it looks something lke this

Authorization: MAC id="a:dfsdfa2",ts="1349277638",nonce="1469030797",mac="ibZ/HXaoz2VgBer3CK7K9vu0po3K+E36K+TQ9Sgcw6o="

I'm sure I'm missing something small, but I cannot see it.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You need to re-format your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the code above is perfect, but I was passing the wrong HTTP method value into it!

Where I was getting the error, I was POST'ing JSON, but I had actually put "GET" into the GetAuthorizationMethod!

Once I'd corrected that, I got an access_token value from Tent.is.

Answer (score 0):

Nicely executed tool at http://buchananweb.co.uk/security01.aspx showing HMAC using MD5 and SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512

Comment: The hash my code was generating. Unfortunately, I was passing the wrong method name, so the signature was invalid.